# Building a react app with socket.io and webpack doesn't work

Tags: node.js, sockets, reactjs, webpack

I was reading all this week about this issue, but any of the solutions that are in the web doesn't work with the project that I am developing. I am working in a webapp using react and its related technologies. To make the compile process I am using the new version of webpack (v2.3.2). I have my server webpack configuration separate from my client webpack configuration. All were working good until I add socket.io in order to make some real-time components. Applying all the solutions that are in the web I am still get the following warning when I run my bundle script:

```
WARNING in ./~/express/lib/view.js
80:29-41 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./~/socket.io/lib/index.js
109:11-32 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./~/engine.io/lib/server.js
115:15-37 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

And when I try to start my project, I get the following error:

```
return /*require.resolve*/(!(function webpackMissingModule() { var e = new Error("Cannot find module \".\""); e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'; throw e; }()));
                                                                                                                                           ^

Error: Cannot find module "."
    at webpackMissingModule (/Users/macpro/Documents/lisa_project/pos_lisa/built/server/index.js:357017:76)
at Server.serveClient   (/Users/macpro/Documents/lisa_project/pos_lisa/built/server/index.js:357020:25)
    at new Server (/Users/macpro/Documents/lisa_project/pos_lisa/built/server/index.js:356959:8)
    at Server (/Users/macpro/Documents/lisa_project/pos_lisa/built/server/index.js:356951:41)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/macpro/Documents/lisa_project/pos_lisa/built/server/index.js:72569:33)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/macpro/Documents/lisa_project/pos_lisa/built/server/index.js:20:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/macpro/Documents/lisa_project/pos_lisa/built/server/index.js:344445:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/macpro/Documents/lisa_project/pos_lisa/built/server/index.js:20:30)
    at /Users/macpro/Documents/lisa_project/pos_lisa/built/server/index.js:66:18
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/macpro/Documents/lisa_project/pos_lisa/built/server/index.js:69:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

Here is my **webpack.client.config.js**

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', path.join(__dirname, '../source/client.jsx')],
  output: {
    filename: 'app.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '../built/statics'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        use: 'json-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2016', 'es2017', 'react'],
          plugins: ['transform-es2015-modules-commonjs'],
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: 'css-loader?modules',
        }),
      },
      {
        test: /\.inline.svg$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader!react-svg-loader?' + JSON.stringify({
          svgo: {
            // svgo options
            plugins: [{removeTitle: false}],
            floatPrecision: 2
          }
        }),
      },
      {
        test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$|^(?!.*\.inline\.svg$).*\.svg$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=400000'
      },
    ],
    noParse: [ path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules/ws') ],
  },
  externals: [ path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules/ws'), path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules/socket.io') ],
  target: 'web',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css', '.json'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.BROWSER': true,
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: '../statics/styles.css',
      ignoreOrder: true,
    }),
  ],
  watch: true,
};
```

Here is my **webpack.server.config.js**

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', path.join(__dirname, '../source/server.jsx')],
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '../built/server'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        use: 'json-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['latest-minimal', 'react'],
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: 'css-loader?modules',
        }),
      },
      {
        test: /\.inline.svg$/,
        loaders: [ 'babel-loader',
          {
            loader: 'react-svg-loader',
            query: {
              svgo: {
                plugins: [{removeTitle: false}],
                floatPrecision: 2
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$|^(?!.*\.inline\.svg$).*\.svg$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=400000'
      },
    ],
    noParse: [ path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules/ws') ],
  },
  externals: [ path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules/ws'), path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules/socket.io') ],
  target: 'node',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css', '.json'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.BROWSER': false,
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: '../statics/styles.css',
      ignoreOrder: true,
    }),
  ],
  watch: true,
};
```

And my **server.jsx** (the important parts)

```
import http from 'http';
import express from 'express';
import socketio from 'socket.io';

const lisaApp = express();
const server = http.createServer(lisaApp);
const io = socketio(server);
```

In advance, thanks for your help and answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found the solution, maybe it helps someone else. In the server side configuration with webpack we have to read the list of directories inside node_modules and give to externals, keeping the "require" of our modules, so we have to add the following to our server side config. (Only the server side, the client side webpack works fine):

```
const fs = require('fs');

var nodeModules = {};
fs.readdirSync('node_modules')
  .filter(function(x) {
    return ['.bin'].indexOf(x) === -1;
  })
  .forEach(function(mod) {
    nodeModules[mod] = 'commonjs ' + mod;
  });
```

This code must be between **const webpack** and **module.exports**. And just after "module" object, add the following line:

```
externals: nodeModules,
```

Hope this helps to somebody.